# torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to run training on an LLM for text generation. Even after various changes to my code, I am still getting this error.

torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 16.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacty of 6.00 GiB of which 4.54 GiB is free. Of the allocated memory 480.02 MiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 1.98 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

Which makes no sense since as it states, my GPU has more than enough space left. This is my first time deploying models, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: How much RAM does your system have?
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/40002

Comment: I've got 64GB of RAM

Comment: One thing you can try is decreasing the batch size. Can you try that'

Comment: Already tried doing that. Batch size is currently set to 1, but I've played around with the number.

Comment: Fragmentation matters; it's not just how much memory but how it's divided. Typically, nvidia's proprietary allocator does better than the default one IME -- the error message tells you where to look to find the relevant configuration docs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. It was my dataset which was formatted in a way that was messing up the tokenizer and creating the issue. After re-creating the dataset, the issue went away.